# How can I split a Google Slide deck into multiple single page decks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

For example. How might I use a script to create 5 1-page decks from a single 5-page deck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create 5 Google Slides files by using each page from a Google Slides file including 5 pages.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Apps Script. Before you use this script, please set `presentationId`. In this script, several Google Slides files including only one page are created by retrieving each page from the Google Slides of `presentationId`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const presentationId = "###"; // Please set the Slides ID.

  SlidesApp.openById(presentationId).getSlides().forEach((s, i) => {
    const newSlide = SlidesApp.create(`page${i + 1}`);
    newSlide.appendSlide(s);
    newSlide.getSlides()[0].remove();
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [create(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app#createname)
- [appendSlide(slide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#appendSlide(Slide))

Comment: If I wanted to name the new 1-page decks based on the title of the page from the source deck would I use getTitle() somehow? Sorry I am new to this and I thought I was better a googling this stuff.

Comment: OK will do. Stackoverflow won't let me ask until tomorrow :( I will do so then.