# How to Split Google Slide Deck and Save Single Slides with Filename and into Specific Folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I have a slide deck where each slide needs to be converted into individual slides. I found this script for splitting a deck into single slides and saving them (This code was provided by @Tanaike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67424448/how-can-i-split-a-google-slide-deck-into-multiple-single-page-decks)):

```
function myFunction() {
  const presentationId = "###"; // Please set the Slides ID.

  SlidesApp.openById(presentationId).getSlides().forEach((s, i) => {
    const newSlide = SlidesApp.create(`page${i + 1}`);
    newSlide.appendSlide(s);
    newSlide.getSlides()[0].remove();
  });
}
```

The script names the slides 1, 2, 3, etc. and saves them into My Drive. I'd like to be able to name each slide based on names listed in a spreadsheet range (e.g. Slide 1 = "Introduction", Slide 2 = "Agenda") and save all of the slides into a specified Google Folder ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the following, it worked for me.

```
function myFunction() {
  const presentationId = "slidesID"; // Please set the Slides ID.
  var slides = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetID").getRange("Sample!A1:A3").getValues(); //Specify the sheet ID and the range where you have the names for each slide

  SlidesApp.openById(presentationId).getSlides().forEach((s, i) => {
    const newSlide = SlidesApp.create(slides[i]);
    newSlide.appendSlide(s);
    newSlide.getSlides()[0].remove();
    var fileID = newSlide.getId();
    var folderID = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderID"); //Specify the folder ID where you want to move the new slides
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).moveTo(folderID)
  });
}
```